# Java: default implementation of List and Set

Tags: java, java-8

In java8, we can generate Set or List from stream, but we don't define which implementation to use, for example, HashSet, TreeSet, LinkedList, or whatever. 
An example here:

`Set<Integer> set = Arrays.stream(arr).distinct().boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());`

So does it have a default implementation? And how can we require it to use specific implementation?

Comment: *at the moment* `toList` is an `ArrayList`; `toSet` is a `HashSet`; `toMap` is a `HashMap`. All of these can be changed via: `toCollection(LinkedList::new)` for example

Comment: @Eugene We are also seriously considering changing the behavior of `toList` et. al. at some point.

Comment: @StuartMarks are you planning to use `SpinedBuffer`? cause I have a hint u will... it might help and improve things a bit; but what to be honest strikes me is that the `Collector API` underneath has no way to pass even a very raw/wrong estimate of the final result and it seems that would be possible in some cases

Comment: @StuartMarks by *obviously* the best coaches are in the stands... I might not see the entire big picture here

Comment: @Eugene It's all in play. Certainly a SpinedBuffer is a possibility, but it's not a List, so it'd have to be upgraded to one. It would be easier if the result were also unmodifiable (fewer methods to implement). Alternatively, toList() could return an instance of the JEP 269 unmodifiable lists (List.of, List.copyOf). This could also be optimized if there were a way to pass sizing information to a collector. A bit complicated, but not impossible.