# Why does Set.of() throw an IllegalArgumentException if the elements are duplicates?

Tags: java, collections, set, java-9

In Java 9 new static factory methods were introduced on the Set interface, called of(), which accept multiple elements, or even an array of elements.

I wanted to turn a list into a set to remove any duplicate entries in the set, which can be done (prior to Java 9) using:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
set.addAll(list);
```

But I thought it would be cool to use this new Java 9 static factory method doing:

```
Set.of(list.toArray())
```

where the `list` is a List of Strings, previously defined.

But alas, java threw an `IllegalArgumentException` when the elements were duplicates, also stated in the Javadoc of the method. Why is this?

***Edit***: this question is not a duplicate of another question about a conceptually equivalent topic, the Map.of() method, but distinctly different. Not all static factory of() methods behave the same. In other words, when I am asking something about the Set.of() method I would not click on a question dealing with the Map.of() method.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is, but as an alternative may I suggest the following Java 8 statement that does the de-duplication for you: `list.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet())`

Comment: Or just use the ancient one-liner `new HashSet<>(list);`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `Set.of()` factory methods produce immutable `Set`s for a **given** number of elements.

In the variants that support a fixed number of arguments (`static <E> Set<E> of​()`, `static <E> Set<E> of​(E e1)`, `static <E> Set<E> of​(E e1,E e2)`, etc...) the requirement of not having duplicates are easier to understand - when you call the method `Set.of(a,b,c)`, you are stating you wish to create an immutable `Set` of **exactly** 3 elements, so if the arguments contain duplicates, it makes sense to reject your input instead of producing a smaller `Set`.

While the `Set<E> of​(E... elements)` variant is different (if allows creating a `Set` of an arbitrary number of elements), it follows the same logic of the other variants. If you pass `n` elements to that method, you are stating you wish to create an immutable `Set` of **exactly** `n` elements, so duplicates are not allowed.

You can still create a `Set` from a `List` (having potential duplicates) in a one-liner using:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(list);
```

which was already available before Java 9.

Answer (score 26):

`Set.of()` is a short way of creating *manually* a small `Set`. In this case it would be a flagrant programming error if you gave it duplicate values, as you're supposed to write out the elements yourself. I.e. `Set.of("foo", "bar", "baz", "foo");` is clearly an error on the programmer's part.

Your *cool* way is actually a really bad way. If you want to convert a `List` to a `Set`, you can do it with `Set<Foo> foo = new HashSet<>(myList);`, or any other way you wish (such as with streams and collecting `toSet()`). Advantages include not doing a useless `toArray()`, the choice of your own `Set` (you might want a `LinkedHashSet` to preserve order) etc. Disadvantages include having to type out a few more characters of code.

The original design idea behind the `Set.of()`, `List.of()` and `Map.of()` methods (and their numerous overloads) is explained here [What is the point of overloaded Convenience Factory Methods for Collections in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918934/what-is-the-point-of-overloaded-convenience-factory-methods-for-collections-in-j) and [here](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/269), where it's mentioned that **The focus is on small collections**, which is something very common all around the internal API, so performance advantages can be had. Although currently the methods delegate to the varargs method offering no performance advantage, this can be easily changed (not sure what the hold-up is on that though).

Comment: @Kayaman while this is correct, for example `List.of...` might be extended to some other "bigger" collections... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47461196/java-default-implementation-of-list-and-set#comment81912802_47461196

Comment: @Eugene sorry, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @Kayaman my bad. what I meant is that your answer is focused on "small by hand-elements" collection as created by `Set.of` and `List.of` for example. The comment from Stuart that I linked to, says that this potentially be extended to bigger collections. I hope I make sense

Comment: @Eugene yeah, I mean I'm *assuming* that the design decision was made based on that, but that's just a `Set.of()` specialty. With `List.of()` and friends, there's no reason why you'd have to assume small, manually created collections. Although, I do believe that the original idea behind the `of()` methods was more about creating small collections (which is why all the overloads) efficiently.

Comment: @Kayaman nitpick: all of them don't yet, starting from 3 elements they still delegate to var-args

Comment: @Eugene yup I remember a few posts discussing the decisions behind it, the current implementations and possible future implementations.

Answer (score 6):

You are expecting this to be a "last-wins", just like `HashSet` I guess, but this was a *deliberate* decision (as Stuart Marks - the creator of these explains). He even has an example like this:

```
Map.ofEntries(
   "!", "Eclamation"
   .... // lots of other entries
   ""
   "|", "VERTICAL_BAR"
);
```

The choice is that since this could be error-prone, they should prohibit it.

Also notice that `Set.of()` returns an immutable `Set`, so you could wrap your `Set` into:

```
Collections.unmodifiableCollection(new HashSet<>(list))
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for `The choice is that since this could be error-prone, they should prohibit it.`?

Comment: Thanks for that link, I'm going to watch it :)

Answer (score 6):

The primary design goal of the `List.of`, `Set.of`, `Map.of`, and `Map.ofEntries` static factory methods is to enable programmers to create these collections by listing the elements explicitly in the source code. Naturally there is a bias toward a small number of elements or entries, because they're more common, but the relevant characteristic here is that the elements are listed out in the source code.

What should the behavior be if duplicate elements are provided to `Set.of` or duplicate keys provided to `Map.of` or `Map.ofEntries`? Assuming that the elements are listed explicitly in the source code, this is likely a programming error. Alternatives such as first-wins or last-wins seem likely to cover up errors silently, so we decided that making duplicates be an error was the best course of action. If the elements are explicitly listed, it would be nice if this were a compile-time error. However, the detection of duplicates isn't detected until runtime,* so throwing an exception at that time is the best we could do.

> * In the future, if all the arguments are constant expressions or are constant-foldable, the Set or Map creation could also be evaluated at compile time and also constant-folded. This might enable duplicates to be detected at compile time.

What about the use case where you have a collection of elements and you want to deduplicate them? That's a *different* use case, and it's not well handled by `Set.of` and `Map.ofEntries`. You have to create an intermediate array first, which is quite cumbersome:

```
Set<String> set = Set.of(list.toArray());
```

This doesn't compile, because `list.toArray()` returns an `Object[]`. This will produce a `Set<Object>` which can't be assigned to `Set<String>`. You want `toArray` to give you a `String[]` instead:

```
Set<String> set = Set.of(list.toArray(new String[0]));
```

This typechecks, but it still throws an exception for duplicates! Another alternative was suggested:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(list);
```

This works, but you get back a `HashSet`, which is mutable, and which takes up a lot more space than the set returned from `Set.of`. You could deduplicate the elements through a `HashSet`, get an array from that, and then pass it to `Set.of`. That would work, but bleah.

Fortunately, this is fixed in Java 10. You can now write:

```
Set<String> set = Set.copyOf(list);
```

This creates an unmodifiable set from the elements of the source collection, and duplicates do *not* throw an exception. Instead, an arbitrary one of the duplicates is used. There are similar methods `List.copyOf` and `Map.copyOf`. As a bonus, these methods skip creating a copy if the source collection is already an unmodifiable collection of the right type.

Comment: Thank you for this updated insight! Choosing an arbitrary duplicate when de-duplicating is exactly what I would expect. Hesitating between first-wins or last-wins seems out of the question for me.

Answer (score 2):

Correct answer:

```
Set.copyOf(list);
```

This code would create set containing unique values from source collection WITHOUT throwing duplicate exception.

Not a single answer for the original question. Only many words explaining why Set.of throwing exception is right (which is arguable).
Also keep in mind that set created that way is immutable which you should use 99% of the time. That's why I always use guava, but recently sonarqube told me that I should switch to Java 9 immutables and DIDN'T mention that behaviour is actually different, ImmutableSet.of silently filters duplicates, Set.of throws duplicate exception.

I've got similar problem when I have 3 variables and want to build an immutable set containing only unique values. What guava does out-of-the box:

```
MyType one = ...;
MyType two = ...;
MyType three = ...;
ImmutableSet.of(one, two, three);
```

with Java 9 you need excessive code:

```
MyType one = ...;
MyType two = ...;
MyType three = ...;
Set.copyOf(List.of(one, two, three));
```

And Java 9 don't even have method

Comment: Well, the original question was why it throws an exception. You are explaining how to make a set of unique values, but that is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

[Set.of​(E... elements)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#of-E...-)

> The element type of the resulting set will be the component type of the array, and the size of the set will be equal to the length of the array.
>
> **Throws:**
>
> ```
> IllegalArgumentException - if there are any duplicate elements
> ```

This is clear that this is not doing any duplicate test since the size of the `Set` will be the length of the array.

The method is just here to be able to get a populated `Set` in a one line

```
Set.of("A","B","C");
```

But you have to be careful on the duplicate yourself. (This will simply iterate the varargs and add them in the new `Set`.